# Send email in php using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email

ok so here i'm looking for some help. i have a contact us form of a website. It has three fields name, email and message. What i need to do is when user fills the form email should be send on admin email which display message of the user and its email and name too. I have a code which is working fine it gives me the message of email sent but when i open mail there is no email. Kindly i need your help. Here is the code

```
    <h3 class="title-big wow fadeIn">Contact Us</h3>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
<?php if($success != ""): ?>
<span class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="color:#D91E18"> <?php echo $success;?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="form-group col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 wow fadeInDown">
<form name="myform" role="form" action="sendmail" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<?php echo form_input($first_name);?>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<?php echo form_input($email);?>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<?php echo form_textarea($message1);?>
<br>
<a class="sign-up-button btn btn-border btn-lg col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1s" href="javascript: submitform()">Submit Query</a>
</div>
</form>
```

controller.php

```
public function contact()
{
    $data['success'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->session->flashdata('message')));
    //$data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->session->flashdata('message')));
    $data['message1'] = array(
            'name'  => 'message1',
            'id'    => 'message1',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'placeholder' => "Enter message here...",
            'size'      =>  32,
            'maxlength' =>  500,
            'rows' => 5,
            'cols' => 41,

        );
        $data['first_name'] = array(
            'name'  => 'first_name',
            'id'    => 'first_name',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'placeholder' => "First Name...",
            'size'      =>  32,
            'maxlength' =>  50,

        );
        $data['email'] = array(
            'name'  => 'email',
            'id'    => 'email',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'placeholder' => "Email Address (Mandatory)",
            'size'      =>  32,
            'maxlength' =>  128,                

        );

    $this->load->view('contact',$data);
}

public function sendmail()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'Name', 'required');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('message1', 'Message', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'required');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('email_confirm', 'Reenter Email Address', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
    {
        $data = array(
        'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
        //'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
        'message1' => $this->input->post('message1'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        );

    //if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
    //{


                $config = array(
            'protocol'  => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'auth' => true,
            'smtp_user' => '********@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => '********'
        );
        $emailsubject = $data['first_name']." ".$data['last_name']." has sent a Query message.";

        $this->load->library('email',$config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        // $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from('********@gmail.com', 'AOTS Lahore Regional Center');
        //$this->email->to('********@gmail.com');
        $this->email->to('********@gmail.com');
        $this->email->cc('********@gmail.com');   
        $this->email->subject($emailsubject);
        $this->email->message($data['message1']."\nEmail ID: ".$data['email']);

        if ($this->email->send()) 
        {
            $data['success'] = "Your Query has been sent successfully... !!";
            //$data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->session->flashdata('message')));
    $data['message1'] = array(
            'name'  => 'message1',
            'id'    => 'message1',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'placeholder' => "Enter message here...",
            'size'      =>  32,
            'maxlength' =>  500,
            'rows' => 5,
            'cols' => 41,

        );
        $data['first_name'] = array(
            'name'  => 'first_name',
            'id'    => 'first_name',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'placeholder' => "First Name...",
            'size'      =>  32,
            'maxlength' =>  50,

        );

        $data['email'] = array(
            'name'  => 'email',
            'id'    => 'email',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'placeholder' => "Email Address (Mandatory)",
            'size'      =>  32,
            'maxlength' =>  128,                

        );

        $this->load->view('contact',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            $data['success'] = show_error( $this->email->print_debugger());
        }

    }
    //}
    else
    { 

        $data['success'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->session->flashdata('message')));



    $data['message1'] = array(
            'name'  => 'message1',
            'id'    => 'message1',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'placeholder' => "Enter message here...",
            'size'      =>  32,
            'maxlength' =>  500,
            'rows' => 5,
            'cols' => 41,

        );
        $data['first_name'] = array(
            'name'  => 'first_name',
            'id'    => 'first_name',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'placeholder' => "First Name...",
            'size'      =>  32,
            'maxlength' =>  50,

        );
        $data['email'] = array(
            'name'  => 'email',
            'id'    => 'email',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'placeholder' => "Email Address (Mandatory)",
            'size'      =>  32,
            'maxlength' =>  128,                

        );
    $this->load->view('contact',$data);
    }
}
```

********@gmail.com is the email where mail should be send

Comment: what is the error ? and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ArunpandianM there is no error

Comment: yea i figured out that you want to receive the details of every filled contact forms. check `my answer` it can done simply with html forms

Comment: use `echo $this->email->print_debugger();die();` before the `if ($this->email->send())` clause and see what it outputs...

Comment: Instead of form tag like you have got use form helper function `<?php echo form_open('controllername/sendmail');?>`

Comment: @Vickel i used it but no output nothing..!!!

Comment: its shows me blank page

Comment: We are removing the emails from your post (to prevent spam) and the password (for security reasons). Please note: you posted your username and password for your email account. It is *very* likely that your account has been compromised. You should change your password immediately, if you have not already done so.

Comment: @EdCottrell thankyou very much for the alert sir

Answer (score 0):

In order to send an  email from (say) `youremailid@gmail.com` to an email id `*****@gmail.com` follow the steps below:

step 1)  the config array as below

```
$config = array(
  'protocol'  => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
  'smtp_port' => 465,
  'auth' => true,
  'smtp_user' => 'youremailid*****@gmail.com',  // email id of sender in this case 'youremailid@gmail.com' is the sender 
  'smtp_pass' => 'passwordofyouremailid',   // password of sender gmail id ie. password of 'youremailid@gmail.com'
  'newline' => "\r\n",
);
```

step 2) Load the email library and call initialize

```
$this->load->library('email',$config); 
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

step 3)  After setting subjects and other info into variables do the following

```
$this->email->from('youremailid****@gmail.com', 'Sender Name'); // sender emailid and name in this case  `youremailid@gmail.com` is sending email

$this->email->to('*****@gmail.com');  // receiver email id in this case '*****@gmail.com' is to whome you want to send . so *****@gmail.com is the email id 

$this->email->cc('*****@gmail.com'); // same as above if you want cc to include   

$this->email->subject($emailsubject);    // subject of email


if ($this->email->send())
{

  // rest of your code
}
```

> remember there youremailid@gmail.com is the sender and *****@gmail.com is the receiver.

Comment: so i don't have to replace 'youremail@domain_registred.com' with anything just copy past it?

Comment: what should i write in  'smtp_pass' ??

Comment: I have edited my answer . please check and if it helped to solve the problem,kindly mark it as answer.

Comment: see the edit , smtp_pass is the password for sender email id

Comment: after implementing your code it gives me this error
An Error Was Encountered

220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP 124sm34854421pgj.57 - gsmtp 

Failed to authenticate password. Error: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 124sm34854421pgj.57 - gsmtp 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

```
 $config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => '********@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => '********',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
```

Comment: You can use any gmail account but make sure you are using correct details of your account ..don't forget to add votes if works and it accepted